# ¿Como obtener valor de variable de sesión en laravel mediante ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo problemas al obtener valor de variable de sesión mediante `jquery` utilizando `ajax`, dado a que cuando mando a imprimir solo obtengo **[object Object],[object Object]**, pero no obtengo ningún valor. Cabe destacar que si hago `POST` mediante un formulario se recarga la pagina(lo que no quiero) y allí si me retorna los valores desde el controlador. El código es el siguiente.

**En mi vista tengo lo siguiente:**

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-reservarG1" onclick="roomadd1();">A</a>
```

**En mi ruta:**

```
Route::get('getrooms', function()
{
   return response(['Hab' => \Session::get('roomcart')]);
});
```

**Mi código ajax jquery es el siguiente:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var roomadd1 = function()
            {   
               var route = "getrooms";
              $.get(route, function(data){
                  console.log("Valores"+data.Hab);
                  $("#nombrespru").val(data.Hab);
              });
           }
</script>
```

**Nota:** El `jquery` esta en la misma vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece muy tonta la razón =) de por que me muestra Object, pero no lo sabia, hasta que hice un par de pruebas. Si lo coloco console.log("Valores"+responseobjetos['habi']);
Me muestra [object][object]
pero en cambio si lo coloco así me muestra los valores
  console.log(responseobjetos['habi']);

Comparto la solución  con ustedes

Answer (score 0):

cambia la consulta `$.get()` a `$.ajax()`,es posible que te solucione el error, quedaria asi:

```
var route = "getrooms";
$.ajax({
    url:route,
    type:'GET',
    success:function(data){
         console.log("Valores"+data.Hab);
         $("#nombrespru").val(data.Hab);
            }

})
```